# Docker Service Stops automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have installed Docker on AWS-EC2 instance (ubuntu), it is working fine and container also running properly.

But at a particular time docker stops automatically, the container also stops and when I start the docker service manually, the container is working fine and the application is up and running.

I do not know how to resolve this, can someone please let me know what the error is?

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, the docker daemon is periodically stopping, and you have to manually start the daemon to get your application running again. No one's going to be able to help you without some logs, so if you're using a normal docker installation, please include the output of `journalctl -u docker.service | tail -n20` to start.